# SQL Server gives invalid column name

Tags: sql-server

Using the following SQL expression but I'm getting an error：

```
SELECT
    t.*, va1.NAME_,
    va2.NAME_
FROM
    ACT_RU_TASK AS t
INNER JOIN ACT_RU_EXECUTION AS e ON t.EXECUTION_ID_ = e.ID_
INNER JOIN ACT_RU_VARIABLE AS va1 ON va1.EXECUTION_ID_ = t.EXECUTION_ID_
INNER JOIN ACT_RU_VARIABLE AS va2 ON va2.EXECUTION_ID_ = t.EXECUTION_ID_
INNER JOIN ACT_RU_IDENTITYLINK AS idlink ON idlink.TASK_ID_ = t.ID_
WHERE
    idlink.USER_ID_ = 3
AND va1.NAME_ = "companyID"
AND va2.NAME_ = "processType"
```

Error infomation:

```
[Err] 42S22 - [SQL Server]Invalid column name 'companyID'.
42S22 - [SQL Server]Invalid column name 'processType'.
```

Why sql server think the query param 'companyID' and "processType" is column name???

TIP:Relatively poor English, I hope you can understand ;)   Thanks

Comment: double-quoted strings in sqlserver are field/table names. you need to use `'`single quotes, e.g. `'companyID'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT
t.*, va1.NAME_,
va2.NAME_
FROM ACT_RU_TASK t
INNER JOIN ACT_RU_EXECUTION e ON t.EXECUTION_ID_ = e.ID_
INNER JOIN ACT_RU_VARIABLE va1 ON va1.EXECUTION_ID_ = t.EXECUTION_ID_
INNER JOIN ACT_RU_VARIABLE va2 ON va2.EXECUTION_ID_ = t.EXECUTION_ID_
INNER JOIN ACT_RU_IDENTITYLINK idlink ON idlink.TASK_ID_ = t.ID_
WHERE idlink.USER_ID_ = 3
AND va1.NAME_ = 'companyID'
AND va2.NAME_ = 'processType'
```